# Clarification in Section 5.10 of K&R 2

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

A pattern recognition program must print all lines containing the patter if the input is find pattern. If the input is find -x pattern, the program must print all lines except the lines containing pattern.

```
// .....
switch(c)
{
case 'x':
    except=1;
    break;
// ......
}

// ......
while(getline(line,MAXLINE)>0)
    {
    line_num++;
    if( (strstr(line,*argv)!=NULL) != except)
        {
        if(number)
            printf("%ld:",linenum);
        printf("%s",line);
        found++;
        }
    }
// ......
```

In the above code from K&R except can either be 1 or 0. How does `if(strstr...)` block functions effectively to handle -x ?

Comment: I did not understand the question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you update your question to show the definition and initialization of `except`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is simple. If the pattern is `"-x"` we should print all lines that do not contain the pattern.

For this pattern `except` is equal to `1`.

So lines that contain the pattern satisfy the condition

```
strstr(line,*argv)!=NULL
```

that is this condition will be always equal to 1 if a line contains the pattern.

Thus if `except` is equal to 1 and the condition `strstr(line,*argv)!=NULL` is equal to 1 we should skip the pattern.

Otherwise if the condition `strstr(line,*argv)!=NULL` is not equal to 1 that is if the pattern is not found then the if statement

```
if( (strstr(line,*argv)!=NULL) != except)
```

yields true and its compound statement is executed.

On the other hand if `except` is equal to `0` then to achieve that the condition in the if statement would evaluate to true we need that the condition `strstr(line,*argv)!=NULL` would be equal to 1.

In fact you can rewrite the if statement

```
if( (strstr(line,*argv)!=NULL) != except)
```

the following way

```
if( ( ( strstr(line,*argv) != NULL ) == 1 && except == 0 ) ||
    ( ( strstr(line,*argv) != NULL ) == 0 && except == 1 ) )
```

Shortly speaking the if statement does the work if either

```
1 and 0
```

or

```
0 and 1
```

If either

```
1 and 1
```

or

```
0 and 0
```

then the if statement will not be executed.

Here 1 and 0 are results of evaluating of the two sub expressions in the if statement.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with the code, however this statement will evaluate to a boolean (`0` or `1`) as `strstr()` will return a pointer to word being searched for or `NULL` if not found:

```
strstr(line, *argv) != NULL
```

So I guess `except` is set to `0` or `1` to effect the "was not found" or "was found" condition.

If `-x` is not passed then `except` is `0`:

```
if ((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != 0)
```

which means if the word was found enter the `if` clause.

If `-x` is passed then `except` is `1`:

```
if ((strstr(line, *argv) != NULL) != 1)
```

which means if the word was found don't enter the `if` clause.

It's confusing code, so I would recommend breaking it down to:

```
const char *word = strstr(line,*argv);
int wasfound = word != NULL;
if (wasfound != except)
{

}
```

and then stepping through with a debugger.  Learning to use a debugger is also vital.

Answer (score 0):

**The `!=` operator has the same truth value as an XOR operation.**  So you can break up

```
if( (strstr(line,*argv)!=NULL) != except)
    {
    if(number)
        printf("%ld:",linenum);
    printf("%s",line);
    found++;
    }
```

into (less efficient but maybe more clear)

```
char found_one_match;
if( strstr(line,*argv) != NULL )
{
    found_one_match = 1;
}
else
{
    found_one_match = 0;
}
found_one_match ^= except;
if (found_one_match)
{
    if(number)
        printf("%ld:",linenum);
    printf("%s",line);
}
found += found_one_match;
```

In other words, `except` reverses the effect of what happens when a pattern is found in the string.